# HTML Image Problem

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my own website and only know some basic HTML, I've searched the web for a bit and can't seem to figure out how to place text under an image and on the left of the image.

So pretty much:

```
[image] [text]
[text]
```

would pretty much be my layout of the web page. At the moment I can only float the image or align it to the left making the text wrap around the image, which I don't want. Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you eloborate?
Do you have an image of how this "should" look?

Comment: Are you trying to make a caption for the image or how should it look? Could you use a table to solve it?

Comment: are you looking for a <table> ?

Comment: it could be a table with two cells, but i dont know how to get rid of the borders

Comment: you can get rid of the border by writing <table border=0>

Comment: alternatively <table style="border-style:none">

Comment: Why do you not want <img align="left"> ?

Comment: is there a way you can get rid of the borders on the cells?

Comment: <td style="border-style:none">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="width:400px; clear:both;">
    <img src="http://media.techworld.com/cmsdata/news/3246520/1998_google.jpg" style="width:300px; float:left;" />
    <div style="width:100px; float:left;">
       text beside image
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">
    text beneath image
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tw2v7/

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple layout matter; I think it should be done without using a table.
You can add an additional "clear: both"-Element behind the text you are floating next to the image, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/nENVN/

Answer (score 0):

Use floats:

```
<img src="" alt="" class="left" /><span>Your text goes here and will wrap around and below the image</span>
<p>More text to sit below the image</p>
```

The text will appear beside the image and then wrap around to the bottom if it's long enough

Comment: This is exactly the solution the OP says that he does not want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using divs instead of tables and then using CSS to size and position the divs

```
<div class="image">Image goes here</div>
<div class="rtext">text on right of image here</div>
<div class="ltext">text below image here</div>
```

This is the basic style for the above

```
.image {width:200px; float:left}
.rtext {width:200px; float:left}
.ltext {width:400px}
```

the ltext div would then be set to a width that is to wide to sit next to the image or the rtext div. It would then be forced to sit below the other 2 divs. This should achieve the look you want.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what youre after?

http://jsfiddle.net/ptzDw/

Basic HTML Structure:

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="left">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x90/7999/fff" alt="image">
        <p>text goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <p>text goes here</p>  
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap { width: 800px; }
#left { width: 300px; float: left; }
#right { width: 400px; float: left; margin-left: 10px;}
```